# How to check for multiple cases based on label name?

Tags: swift, firebase, if-statement, switch-statement, refactoring

I have a view controller that contains a collection view on multiple categories. Different data and details including photos related to that category are fetched. I do not know how to make a case of switch statement regarding this. Writing the same code over and over does not seem like a good idea.

I have at least 14 different cells to cover...

Heres what I got

```swift
// Fetch posts based on trend name/hashtag
func fetchPosts() {
    if trendName == "Bike Shorts" {
        print("Fetching posts with the hashtag bikeshorts")
        HASHTAG_POST_REF.child("bikeshorts").observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
            let postId = snapshot.key
            Database.fetchPost(with: postId, completion: { (post) in
                self.posts.append(post)
                self.collectionView?.reloadData()
            })
        }
    } else {
        if trendName == "Animal Prints" {
            self.trendDetails = "This is the label for animal prints"
            HASHTAG_POST_REF.child("animalprints").observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
                let postId = snapshot.key
                Database.fetchPost(with: postId, completion: { (post) in
                    self.posts.append(post)
                    self.collectionView?.reloadData()
                })
            }
        }
    } else {
        if self.trendName == "Bermunda Shorts" {
            self.trendDetails = "This is the label for bermunda shorts"
            HASHTAG_POST_REF.child("bermundashorts").observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
                let postId = snapshot.key
                Database.fetchPost(with: postId, completion: { (post) in
                    self.posts.append(post)
                    self.collectionView?.reloadData()
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The only significant difference between the three that I can say are the `trendName` and the `child` request.  I'd consider making a dictionary or `enum` which grouped those elements together so it would be easier to simply call `HASHTAG_POST_REF` by looking up the corresponding key

Comment: @MadProgrammer you wouldn't happen to mind showing me an example would you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is too much repetition here, I wouldn't use an if or a switch statement. The only things that change is the data.

Try something more dynamic...

```
struct Trend {
   let name: String
   let details: String
   let childValue: String
}

let trends = [
   Trend(name: "Bike Shorts", details: "Fetching posts with the hashtag bikeshorts", childValue: "bikeshorts"),
]

func fetchPosts() {
     let trend = trends.first { $0.name = trendName }

     self.trendDetails = trend.details
     HASHTAG_POST_REF.child(trend.childValue).observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
         let postId = snapshot.key
         Database.fetchPost(with: postId, completion: { (post) in
             self.posts.append(post)
             self.collectionView?.reloadData()
         })
     }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I would use enum to manage with your categories
Here is some code of how to

```
enum Trend: String {

    case bike = "bikeshorts"
    case animal = "animalprints"

    static let allValues: [Trend] = [bike, animals]

    var name: String {
        switch self {
        case .bike: return "Bike Shorts"
        case .animal: return "Animal Prints"
        }
    }

}

var trend: Trend = .bike

func fetchPosts() {

    HASHTAG_POST_REF.child(trend.rawValue).observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in

        let postId = snapshot.key
        Database.fetchPost(with: postId, completion: { (post) in
            self.posts.append(post)
            self.collectionView?.reloadData()
        })


    }

}
```

You can obtain trend variable didSet to call fetch func or iterate by allValues

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this post, although I accepted the last answer  I will upvote your answer as well as it helped!

Answer (score 1):

## You could...

Use a dictionary to map the the "name" and the API "key"

```
let trendNamePair: [String:String] = [
    "Bike Shorts": "bikeshorts",
    "Animal Prints", "animalprints",
    "Bermunda Shorts", "bermundashorts",
    ]

func fetchPosts() {
    guard let key = trendNamePair[trendNamePair] else {
        // Do some error handling
        return
    }
    HASHTAG_POST_REF.child(key).observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in

        let postId = snapshot.key
        Database.fetchPost(with: postId, completion: { (post) in
            self.posts.append(post)
            self.collectionView?.reloadData()
        })

    }

}
```

## You could...

Do something slightly more complicated and combine this information into a common structure

```
struct Request {
    let trendName: String
    let apiKey: String
    let description: String?
}
```

This would then form part of your model and when required, you would pass that to your fetch post

```
func fetchPosts(_ request: Request) {
    self.trendDetails = request.description
    HASHTAG_POST_REF.child(request.apiKey).observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in

        let postId = snapshot.key
        Database.fetchPost(with: postId, completion: { (post) in
            self.posts.append(post)
            self.collectionView?.reloadData()
        })

    }

}
```

## You could...

Also do something with enums, which would be a good use case for a limited number of possible options, but has it's own complexity and issues

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this post, although I accepted the last answer  I will upvote your answer as well as it helped too!